# Transform formaction to data-cke-pa-formaction in CKEditor 4.5.8

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor v.4.5.8, looking at the [htmldataprocessor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/source/htmldataprocessor.html) plugin.

I'm seeing that `on*` attributes (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.) are transformed to `data-cke-pa-on*` protected attributes for display in CKEditor's editable regions, which is a useful way to prevent scripts from executing in the editor context.

Is it possible, **without turning on Advanced Content Filtering** (leaving `config.allowedContent = true`), to also transform any `formaction` attributes of `<button>` elements, added in the Source editor, into non-executable `data-cke-pa-formaction` attributes in the WYSIWYG editor? And can this be accomplished within a config.js file, rather than editing compiled ckeditor.js or htmldataprocessor.js directly?

I've tried adding the following to config.js:

```js
CKEDITOR.on('instanceLoaded', function(e) {
    e.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
        elements: {
            button: function( el ) {
                if( el.attributes && el.attributes['formaction'] ){
                    el.attributes['data-cke-pa-formaction'] = el.attributes['formaction'];
                    delete el.attributes['formaction'];
                }
            }
        }
    } );

    e.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
        elements: {
            button: function( el ) {
            }
        }
    } );
});
```

This works perfectly when switching back and forth between the source editor and the WYSIWYG editor, but on initial load, the element is still loading in as `<button formaction="javascript:alert(document.domain)">Click me!</button>`. I've tried using other events for CKEDITOR.on ([beforeGetData](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-beforeGetData), [getData](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-getData), etc.), but based on debugging, it appears that those functions are never called within the config script. Is there somewhere else I should be putting the `addRules` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code (**ACF needs to be enabled**):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent : 'button[name,type,formaction]'
});
editor.on('pluginsLoaded', function( evt ){
    evt.editor.filter.addTransformations( [
        [
            {
             element:'button',
             left: function( el ) {
                return el.name == 'button';
             },
             right: function( el, tools ) {
                if( el.attributes && el.attributes['formaction'] ){
                    el.attributes['data-cke-pa-formaction'] = el.attributes['formaction'];

                    delete el.attributes['formaction'];
                }
             }
            }
        ]
    ]);
});
```

If you e.g. paste below HTML:

```
<button name="Test Button" type="submit" formaction="/action_page2.php" />Click me!</button>
```

You will get:

```
<button data-cke-pa-formaction="/action_page2.php" name="Test Button" type="submit">Click me!</button>
```

As I have explained at the start, ACF needs to be enabled thus if you are not familiar with it, please see below links:

- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-addTransformations
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent

---

**EDIT:** If you can't use ACF, you cat try `dataFilter` and `htmlFilter`:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        extraAllowedContent : 'button[*]{*}(*)',
        on: {
            pluginsLoaded: function( evt ) {

                evt.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
                    elements: {
                        button: function( el ) {
                            if( el.attributes && el.attributes['formaction'] ){
                                el.attributes['data-cked-pa-formaction'] = el.attributes['formaction'];
                                delete el.attributes['formaction'];
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } );

                //when you get data from editor
                evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                    elements: {
                        button: function( el ) {
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
});
```

NOTE: If you want permanent change, you can't use `data-cke` attributes because they get auto changed when getting raw HTML. For permanent change you should use e.g. `data-cked-`

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer - is there a way to accomplish the same thing with ACF disabled? The context in which CKEditor is being used necessitates that we have `config.allowedContent = true;`, I'd just like to transform `formaction` attributes on `button` elements to something more benign in the editor without altering the underlying `formaction` attribute on the server side.

Comment: I have udated my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, @j.swiderski, but I'm still not quite there; I've updated my question to reflect my implementation of your answer and the results.

Comment: The pluginsLoaded event is assigned to particular editor instance and not global `CKEDITOR` object. You have to call that event on HTML page in editor instance configuration, exactly as I have shown you and not in `config.js`. Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-pluginsLoaded